# Has Stephen Colbert ever been on Saturday Night Live (SNL)?

Tags: saturday-night-live

Whether [in character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Colbert_%28character%29), [out of character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Colbert), or portraying other characters (either as real-world self or while 'in character' subsequently portraying those characters), has US comedian Stephen Colbert ever had an appearance on SNL, even if momentary?

As such an iconic figure in current-day American comedy television, it is surprising there appears to be almost no appearance from him in such a *fellow* iconic American comedy fixture as SNL; even more so given that the two parties are based in the same location, New York City!

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Maybe I am missing something here, but this seems to be a simple trivia question (which are [off-topic](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here). If it is not, please edit your question to explain what further relevance his appearance in the show has.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry about that, my SE instincts told me it'd be the type of question that enjoys being documented (since previous to this answer, 'Google' didn't seem to provide an answer) - and at a brief glance, other questions seemed to be similar (questions about mere facts) - but I guess I was mistaken! t least I know now, thanks! As for the relevance, it is simply that Colbert is such a fixture in American comedy and so is SNL, and it is surprising there isn't much of a meeting of the two...

Comment: I am not saying your question is necessarily off-topic, maybe you just have to explain a bit further why this would be an interesting fact to document. (as you started to do in your comment) I am not very familiar with the US comedy scene, so it might be obvious to you why this is interesting, but your question still could use that explanation to make it interesting to people outside the US.

Comment: Sorry to cause a bit of a moderator stir, but I think it's good to contribute to growing pains in working out what this site is meant for, we'll all learn from it! If unearthing obscure information that one at first can't think of how to even go about getting to the bottom of it (and I'm a power googler myself), I think a quality Q&A network like SE is exactly what it should exist for - others clearly appreciate this question, and I myself didn't think of IMDB! So maybe in future as long as it's not a 'what movies has Meg Ryan starred in' Q, it should be allowed if it's not a 'LMGTFY' case?...

Comment: I think in the current (edited) form the question is fine and should be reopened. You have to understand that the distinction between mere trivia that can easily be looked up on IMDB and interesting questions is always hard and we have to maintain a certain level of quality on this site. Usually it will come down if a question can sufficiently justify why it is not just trivia (like who was acting where), and you did that now.

Comment: Thanks! :) With good practice from all parties, it can now live on as a free-standing question and I (and hopefully others observing) learned something at the same time :). Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Accoring to his [IMDB filmography](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0170306/?ref_=tt_cl_t2), he is credited with two skits, [Season 22 Epi 5, Chris Rock/Wallflowers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0694723/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_71) and [Season 22 Epi 11, David Allen Grier/Snoop Doggy Dog](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0694710/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_71). All of the rest of his SNL credits are either as Writer or Voice over work in other skits.

One interesting tidbit (to me anyway) is that while Colbert was a writer for SNL from 1996 through 2011 (not all episodes, but several a year) and he has provided voice over work for episodes (that he also wrote for) for that same period, AND he has a hit show and fame from [The Daily Show](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115147/?ref_=nm_flmg_slf_5) AND his [own eponymous show](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458254/?ref_=nm_flmg_slf_3).... he has only been on two episodes.

You'd think he'd have been invited to host it by now, at the very least.

Comment: Ambiguously Gay Duo!